# Why is C99 designated initializers not be supported by VC++ 2013 RC as promised?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c++11, initialization

[The official blog of VC++ team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2013/06/28/cpp-conformance-roadmap.aspx) has said: "C99 designated initializers will be supported in VC++ 2013 RTM."

However, the following code is rejectd by VC++ 2013 RC:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    double b;

    A()          = default; // OK as promised
    virtual ~A() = default; // OK as promised
    A(const A&)  = delete;  // OK as promised
};

int main()
{
    A a = { .b = 3.14159 }; // Error! It is NOT as promised!
}
```

Comment: Did you notice `RC` and `RTM` difference?

Comment: I think RC should be almost identical to RTM, especially in such a case.

Comment: Apart from Jesse's point, "the RTM version will also include a few tactical C99 language extensions when compiling C code" - what you are compiling is clearly not C code.

Comment: Although according to [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/09/09/visual-studio-2013-rc-now-available.aspx) it should be supported. What happens if you change the code to `struct A { int a; double b; };` and compile as C (change to .c ext)?

Comment: Maybe they're only supported in the C compiler and not in the C++ compiler?

Comment: Why are you mixing C and C++?

Comment: This question cannot be answered technically. You need to direct this at Microsoft, not at Stackoverflow. 

Comment: Think about it. C++ has constructors and initializer lists that can serve the same purpose. Designated initializers are a feature "extension" according to what the blog stated. I wouldn't expect any C++ compiler to support designated initializers, but it is a much needed C feature IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the same page you linked:

> Herb also announced that, in response to customer requests, the RTM version will also **include** a few tactical **C99** language extensions **when compiling C code**, so that some popular community libraries (including FFmpeg) will now be able to compile with Visual C++ 2013.

So the designated initializers will be only in C code, not in C++ code. I see `A` is defined in C++ syntax, there :-)